# не работает добавление слова в wordforms.txt?

Tags: sphinx

Добавила слова в цщкв
Тура > Tura
не работает, если введешь слово "Тура".
В бд есть Tura 1, Tura 2
что надо сделать, чтобы заработало?
а по остальным почему то-работает...

```
sudo service sphinxsearch status
● sphinxsearch.service - LSB: Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Сб 2018-10-13 20:34:12 MSK; 1min 13s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3052 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3146 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sphinxsearch.service
           ├─3150 /usr/bin/searchd
           └─3151 /usr/bin/searchd

окт 13 20:34:11 good sphinxsearch[3146]: WARNING: invalid mapping (destination contains blended characters) (wordform='емкабель > ЭМ-Кабель'). Fix your wordforms file '/etc/sphinxsearch/wordforms/wor
окт 13 20:34:11 good sphinxsearch[3146]: WARNING: invalid mapping (destination contains blended characters) (wordform='им кабель > ЭМ-Кабель'). Fix your wordforms file '/etc/sphinxsearch/wordforms/wo
окт 13 20:34:11 good sphinxsearch[3146]: WARNING: invalid mapping (destination contains blended characters) (wordform='имкабель > ЭМ-Кабель'). Fix your wordforms file '/etc/sphinxsearch/wordforms/wor
окт 13 20:34:11 good sphinxsearch[3146]: WARNING: invalid mapping (destination contains blended characters) (wordform='имкабиль > ЭМ-Кабель'). Fix your wordforms file '/etc/sphinxsearch/wordforms/wor
окт 13 20:34:11 good sphinxsearch[3146]: WARNING: invalid mapping (destination contains blended characters) (wordform='эм кабел > ЭМ-Кабель'). Fix your wordforms file '/etc/sphinxsearch/wordforms/wor
окт 13 20:34:11 good sphinxsearch[3146]: Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
окт 13 20:34:11 good sphinxsearch[3146]: Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
окт 13 20:34:11 good sphinxsearch[3146]: Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
окт 13 20:34:12 good sphinxsearch[3146]: sphinxsearch.
окт 13 20:34:12 good systemd[1]: Started LSB: Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine.

проделывала
sudo service sphinxsearch stop
sudo indexer --all
sudo service sphinxsearch start
```

и почему то варнинги появляются... дубляжей вроде нет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что ЭМ-Кабель содержит дефис который у вас занесен в секцию blend_chars в индексе

Comment: и нужно этот дефис убрать из секции blend_chars ?

Comment: мы же хотим , чтобы искалось слово  с дефисом ...

Comment: согласно статье http://chakrygin.ru/2013/07/sphinx-search.html

Comment: Думаете, из-за этого не ищется этот синоним?
из-за ошибок в вордформ.

Comment: но остальные синонимы вроде ищутся...

Comment: Вам нужна однозначная трактовка синонима:
емкабель -> Эмкабиль или емкабель -> Эм кабиль
Бленд чар говорит что дефис нужно читать и как разделитель слов и как обычный символ в слове